# postgresql-9.5 on CentOS 7 won't start on boot (PGDATA on mount point)

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I am trying to get postgresql-9.5 to start on boot on CentOS 7.

I've followed the installation and startup steps here https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation
And have tried some additional troubleshooting from this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492893/unable-to-start-postgresql-9-5-on-centos-7

It might be relevant that I am using a custom PGDATA directory that is a mount point.  (`/mnt/data`)

The database was initialized pointing to the `/mnt/data` directory.

`su postgres -c "/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl initdb -D /mnt/data"`

I made the necessary changes to the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service` file to point to the `/mnt/data` directory.

The service was enabled and started successfully.

`systemctl enable postgresql-9.5`

`systemctl start postgresql-9.5`

After rebooting, `systemctl status postgresql-9.5` shows the following:

```
● postgresql-9.5.service - PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-04-06 00:53:02 EDT; 4min 36s ago
  Process: 9911 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 06 00:53:02 pgdev-fl1 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server...
Apr 06 00:53:02 pgdev-fl1 systemd[1]: postgresql-9.5.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 06 00:53:02 pgdev-fl1 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 9.5 database server.
Apr 06 00:53:02 pgdev-fl1 systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.5.service entered failed state.
Apr 06 00:53:02 pgdev-fl1 systemd[1]: postgresql-9.5.service failed.
```

However, I can immediately run `systemctl start postgresql-9.5` and it loads just fine, using the `/mnt/data` directory.

Thinking it might be an issue of timing and it trying to start the service before the mount point exists, I included `Requires=mnt-data.mount` in the `[Unit]` section of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service`, and re-enabled the service after a `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Yet still it errors out with the same message upon boot.

Running `/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}` generates no output for me so I am at a loss as to where to continue troubleshooting this issue.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Update - 4/6/16

After checking `journalctl` it's apparent that it is trying to load the postgresql-9.5 service before the iSCSI volume is mounted, even though the `Requires` directive was included.

Answer (score 1):

After rereading https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files it's become apparent to me that `Requires` doesn't behave how I thought it would.

Changing the directive to `After` solved the issue and made the postgresql-9.5 service wait until the mount point was available.

`Requires` without the `After` will try and load them simultaneously.

You can use `Requires` with `After` to imply the dependency relationship.